# Connecting frontend to backend: passportjs-facebook, angular2, expressjs, authentication

Tags: angular, passport.js

tldr: How do I route to facebook for authentication and then retrieve and use the json object it returns for use in a callback function?

My express backend and facebook authentication strategy is working, I can type `localhost:3000/users/auth`, it will redirect me to facebook where I login and get redirected to `users/auth/callback` with the json success and my token. It populates my profile data into mongodb backend.

But I don't know how to connect this to my angular 2 frontend. I have a login button which I want to redirect me to facebook and I have created an auth service but I don't know what to do with it, I tried routing to it and I tried this its not correct, I need to route to that page and then retrieve the callback json but I dont know how.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: Http, 
              private router: Router) { }

  private users: User[] = [];

  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  login () {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/auth', {withCredentials: true})
        .subscribe((data) => {
          if(data.json().success) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('auth_key', data.json().token);
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
          }
          resolve(this.isLoggedIn);
        })
    })
  }
```